# sqlalchemy returns instance of the class but it does not print correctly

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have code like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String,and_,insert,select,Integer,delete
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# Define your model
Base = declarative_base()

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    product = Column(String)
    market = Column(String)
    idea = Column(String)

# Create a connection to your database
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg://postgres:2001@localhost:5432/postgres')
# MyTable.__table__.drop(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Create a session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

session.execute(
    insert(MyTable),
    [
        {"id":1,"product":"BG","market":"JY","idea":"sad"},
        {"id":2,"product":"GF","market":"HN","idea":"happy"},
    ]
    )
session.commit()

results = session.scalars(select(MyTable).where(MyTable.id==1)).all()
print(results)
```

Results is :

```
[<__main__.MyTable object at 0x103818650>]
```

I was expecting to have the print results as:

```
[MyTable(id=1,product='BG',market='JY',idea='sad')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override `__repr__` to change that output.

```py
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    product = Column(String)
    market = Column(String)
    idea = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        # There is probably a better way to pull attributes than using table columns but this works.
        attrs = ','.join(f"{col.name}={getattr(self, col.name)}" for col in self.__table__.c)
        return f'<MyTable {attrs}'
```

Comment: Get it, but the docs show the printing as I intended without any modifications. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html. That is for version 2